# Sending form-data with retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an endpoint where I PUT some data, where the Content-Type should be form-data.

I'm using

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @PUT("/api/v1/clients/profile/all_details")
 Call<ResponseBody> postUserProfile(@FieldMap Map<String, String> userParams);
```

but while sending the request, the form-data is encoded like

```
food_allergy=%5Beggs%2C%20milk%2C%20nuts%2C%20none%5D&diet_prefer=Non%20Vegetarian&age=25&exercise_level=Moderate&email=Email&name=Veeresh&height=175&prompt-qgreet3=I%27m%20ready%21&gender=Female&health_condition=%5Bdiabetes%2C%20PCOD%5D&weight=69
```

How do I remove the encoding?

I tried this blog

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap

Comment: Write a regex which starts which checks for % as first item and & as last item.

Comment: Any other alternatives instead of regex?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to encode the form data then you can try like this

`@PUT("/api/v1/clients/profile/all_details")
Call<ResponseBody> postUserProfile(@QueryMap Map<String, String> userParams);`

**EDIT 1**

```
@Multipart
        @PUT("/api/v1/clients/profile/all_details")
        Call<ResponseBody> postUserProfile(@Part(username) RequestBody username, @Part(password) RequestBody password);
```

And here is how to get requestBody from String.

```
String username = "username";
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), username);

String password = "password";
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), password);
```

Comment: No, it cannot be @QueryMap, QueryMap works adding to the url

Comment: The key's that are used in @Part are dynamic and I cannot hard code them

Comment: Then you can use `@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap` instead of `@Part`

Answer (score 0):

You can first of all replace all the % by using

```
string.replace("%","");
```

And do the rest the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`@FieldMap` has an element called `encoded` which is `false` by default.

If you set it to `true`, you're saying my data is already encoded and I don't want `Retrofit` to handle the encoding.

`@FieldMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> userParams`